# Restore computer with a virus

Tags: virus, restore

I have had a virus for a while now and it has got to a point were I can't get past the welcome screen when I start up my computer, I know my computer has not got slower from use because before the virus it took my computer 2 seconds to get to the desktop... Someone please help I can't use my computer at all!!!!

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable (albeit cliche at this point) solution, presuming Windows, is as follows:

1. Back up your data to an external hard drive (which you should be doing already); take care to back up data only, not programs.
2. Run an antivirus scan on the backup (antivirus, not just antimalware; e.g. Comodo or AVG or Avast or Avira).
3. Reinstall Windows (reformat the drive and start fresh).
4. Before restoring your data, install antivirus software.
5. Run an antivirus scan on the backup data again (in particular things like Word documents).
6. Restore your data.
7. In the future, always have an antivirus running, do regular malware scans (e.g. Malwarebytes), back up your data regularly, and be careful.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your computer in safe mode with network access by pressing F8 between your BIOS splash screen and the Windows Loading screen (another way that could work is pressing the power button during 5 seconds when windows is on login screen... but I really don't recommend it since it can corrupt your files).

If it works, download malwarebytes, download the latest definitions and do a complete scan:

http://fr.malwarebytes.org/techbench/

If it doesn't work, find another computer and burn a CD with Kaspersky Rescue Disk:

http://support.kaspersky.com/4162

Boot it on your computer and, again, do a complete scan on your machine with the latest definitions.

Edit:

[You may want to see this better explained thread](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)